# SQL query using join table

Tags: mysql

I have the tables imagecapturing, harddisks and imagecapturing_harddisks.

imagecapturing:

```
id, manuscript_shelfmark
61, foo
70, bar
90, baz
```

harddisks:

```
id, harddisk_name
4, hd-1
5, hd-2
6, hd-3
```

imagecapturing_harddisks:

```
id, imagecapturing_id, harddisk_id
445,    61,            4
446,    61,            5
447,    61,            6
448,    70,            6
449,    90,            6
```

How can I select all manuscript_shelfmarks from harddisk_id = 6 ?

```
manuscript_shelfmark, harddisk_id
foo,               6
bar,               6
baz,               6
```

Comment: Should the resulting row be only `foo` here? It's easier to help if the expected results match the example inputs.

Comment: yes, you're right, I updated the ids on imagecapturing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll note that table `harddisks` is unneeded so its omitted.

```
SELECT manuscript_shelfmark, harddisk_id
FROM imagecapturing_harddisks
JOIN imagecapturing ON imagecapturing_id=imagecapturing.id
WHERE imagecapturing_harddisks.harddisk_id=6
```